# How do I create a grid view in PHP that will allow me to manually input data?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Using PHP, I want to create a database in MySQL, and to create a grid view to enter the following information in three columns.

```
no     name     company
234    xyz      abc
543    pqr      def
```

I want to import this data into my table in MySQL from an Excel spreadsheet.

Is there an equivalent to component factory in PHP?

Comment: Have you made an attempt at this yourself or are you just expecting people to give you a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try below

Grid-based editing, create, read, update and delete (CRUD), are the most common operations for web developers. With phpGrid web-based data editing is easy. Even with little programming background, one can develop professional looking, AJAX-enabled PHP datagrids in just a few minutes.

http://phpgrid.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fgetcsv function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php